# How to reduce the number of outliers in OneClassSVM in sklearn in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, outliers

I am using oneclasssvm as follows.

```
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM

clf = OneClassSVM(random_state=42)
clf.fit(X)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X)

print(len(np.where(y_pred_train == -1)[0]))
```

However, I get more than 50% of my data as outliers. I would like to know if there is a way to reduce the numebr of outliers in one class svm.

I tried `contamination`. However, it seems like oneclasssvm does not support contamination.

Is there any other approach that I can use?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be interested in understanding the variance, dimensionality, number of sample points you are using but my first suggestion would be to try:

```
clf = OneClassSVM(random_state=42, gamma='scale')
```

From the [Docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html)

> Current default is ‘auto’ which uses 1 / n_features, if gamma='scale'
>   is passed then it uses 1 / (n_features * X.var()) as value of gamma.
>   The current default of gamma, ‘auto’, will change to ‘scale’ in
>   version 0.22. ‘auto_deprecated’, a deprecated version of ‘auto’ is
>   used as a default indicating that no explicit value of gamma was
>   passed.

Answer (score 2):

You can control how many data points in your training data are labeled as outliers by controlling the `nu` parameter of OneClassSVM.

From API docs, nu is, `An upper bound on the fraction of training errors and a lower bound of the fraction of support vectors. Should be in the interval (0, 1]. By default 0.5 will be taken.`

I suggest that you have a labeled validation set and then tune your SVM hyperparameters, like `nu`. `kernel` etc. for best performance on the labeled validation set.